# IIS ASP Classic redirect leads to 'invalid DOCTYPE' error

Tags: html, iis

Configured IIS as Web server.

Used an URL for redirect to `http://FQDN/longview/testSSO.html` another web client. But it giving me the error in redirect as

> http 405 method not support POST request

Then I have installed the 'ASP' using 'windows Features Turn on or off' configured the ‘ASP’ to *.html request in Handler Mappings in IIS. Now it shows error in IE browser.

> invalid DOCTYPE, use valid `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, posting to Html files is not possible in IIS without installing a backend language to interpret the HTML files rather than the IIS static file handler.

make sure you installed iis ASP, ISAPI Extensions, static content feature.

[image]

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="htm" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule"  scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and to resolve the

> invalid DOCTYPE, use valid

just insert `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your website’s HTML page.

Comment: To make it more clear, I have two 3rd party Web App. which uses IIS as Web server. Both are working well independently. I would like to integrate both using an URL for the ticket to generate in first URL and redirect to another application for my  project purpose. First URL generated the Ticket, and redirection is also working but its giving error as "405 POST method not supported". I did the above what you have suggested earlier. But its saying in IE browser 'invalid Doctype' but in chrome ''An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Pease contact the system administrator."

Comment: Error: Active Server Pages Error 'ASP 0138'
Nested script block
/longview/TestTM1SSO.html, line 30
A script block must not be in another script block. after enabled scriptErrorSentToBrowser = true in IIS,

Comment: both app are 3rd party, so I cant share the code. Now I am looking for the different approach so instead of redirecting I am trying to set a dynamic  'Server Variable' in IIS. So that I can read this in the Application using a function. But here my question is, is it possible to set the "CAM_Passport" as server variable in IIS?

Comment: you could set a custom server variable by using the iis URL rewrite rule module. in iis URL rewrite module Under Action's select View Server Variables under 'Manager Server variables'. Click on Add from Actions and type in CAM_Passport on the Add Server Variable dialog box. Next click on Edit under Inbound Rules under Actions. Under the Server Variables section click on Add. From the Set Server variables, the dialog box selects the server variables that we just created CAM_Passport from the drop-down. Set the value. Click on ok and restart the webserver.

Comment: Yes I have tried the same, but CAM_Passport generate SSOTOKEN dynamically   not the static one. Is there a possibility of setting this?